# pass auth::user as data variable with route

Tags: php, laravel, url, routes

I want that when the user click the profile page i want to pass `Auth::user()->username` as argument to my userController's show method.I have the profile link as following:

```
<li><a href="{{URL::to('/profile')}}">Profile</a></li>
```

And in my route i have the following route

```
Route::get('/profile/{username}',function(){
     return View::make('user.show')->with($username);
});
```

my question is how i can set `username` in my `'/profile/{username}'` as `Auth::user()->username` when i click the profile link?currently the profile link does not attach any parameter with it

Answer (score 2):

First of all
`{{URL::to('/profile')}}` is not pointing to `Route::get('/profile/{username})` url,there are two different routes

So what you need to do is either change the link , i.e.

```
{{URL::to('/profile/' . \Auth::user()->username)}}
```

and then in your route file

```
Route::get('/profile/{username}',function($username){
    return View::make('user.show')->with(['username' => $username]);
});
```

//note that you need to pass the array in with() method
or you can do this

```
Route::get('/profile/{username}',function($username){
    return View::make('user.show',compact('username'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When the user clicks on profile link:

```
<li>
  <a href="{!! route('user.show', Auth::user()->username) !!}">My Profile</a>
</li>
```

The UserController@show method is called.

```
<?php

// routes.php

Route::get('profile/{username}', 'UserController@show')->name('user.show');

// UserController.php

public function show($username)
{
    $user = User::whereUsername($username)->first();

    return view('user.show', compact('user'));
}
```

and a View response is returned to the user.

@update

If you need is just redirect the control to the UserController@show method, you can do this:

```
<li>
  <a href="{!! route('user.profile', Auth::user()->username) !!}">My Profile</a>
</li>

<?php

// routes.php

Route::get('profile/{username}', function ($username) {
    return redirect()->route('user.show', Auth::id());
})->name('user.profile');
```

Now if you want customize the UserController@show action:

```
<li>
  <a href="{!! route('user.profile', Auth::user()->username) !!}">My Profile</a>
</li>
```

The UserController@show method is called.

```
<?php

// routes.php

Route::resource('user', 'UserController', ['except' => ['show']);
Route::get('profile/{username}', 'UserController@profile')->name('user.profile');
```

Now you can delete the UserController@show method if you want or change the profile method name to show.

```
// UserController.php

public function profile($username)
{
    $user = User::whereUsername($username)->first();

    return view('user.show', compact('user'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick way is to setup a redirect from /profile and it won't break the functionality if they want to view someone else's profile.

```
Route::get('/profile',function(){
    return Redirect::to('/profile/'.Auth::user()->username);
}
```

However, I'd recommend doing an Auth::check() before the redirect.

Comment: i don't have a page called profile .i have to send it to user.show page

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  My code will just redirect the user and end up using the profile/username route you have in your question.

Answer (score 0):

i did something like the following

```
<li><a href="{{URL::to('/profile')}}">Profile</a></li>
```

and in route.php:

```
Route::get('/profile',function(){
        return redirect()->route('user.show',[Auth::user()->username]);

    });
```